# Allure reports how get meaningful text

Tags: java, selenium, testng, reporting, allure

I'm kinda stumped at the moment because I'm not exactly sure how to get my textoutputs into my allure reports.

All my functions that produce text include an if-else block that looks like this:

```
public void sendDetails (WebElement inputfield, String input) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(inputfield));
    inputfield.sendKeys(input);

    //System.out.println(inputfield.getAttribute("value"));
    if (inputfield.getAttribute("value").contains(input)){
        Reporter.log("details input successfully for "+inputfield.getAttribute("type"), true);
    } else {
        Assert.fail("details couldn't be entered for "+inputfield.getAttribute("type"));
    }
}
```

Whats the best way for me to get my text into allure? Should I rewrite my functions so they work with TestNGs @Attachement method? I'm not sure I want to change most of my void functions to String. I'm also not sure if this would even work with the text in Assert.fail then.

If you need more infos I will provide, just any kind of nudge into the right direction would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Why you want to log that ?

Comment: @PDHide so I know what the test did at what time and were it might have failed

Comment: You have the assert for that right if assert is not thrown then it passed why to explicitly log that , your question is how to create report or how to add logs in a better way to the report

Comment: @PDHide so i should switch my ifelse to asserts and that gets logged then?

Comment: if it fails it should get logged in report , use listener classes in your testng or junit framework to capture the test failures and add to report